# Cannot create site in different web application - Silverlight Client Object Model

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I am developing a Silverlight application. It interacts with SharePoint 2010 using SharePoint Silverlight Managed Client Object Model.

One of the application functionalities is to create a SharePoint 2010 site. If the provided URL of the site that is to be created belongs to the same SharePoint web application where the Silverlight application is loaded, the site gets created without any issues. However, if the URL targets a SharePoint web application different than the one where the Silverlight application is loaded, I get the Security exception.

In the site creation method I am creating the new client context that matches the specified URL and then calling Object Model's site creation method:

```
this.ClientContext = new ClientContext(uriFromApplication);

WebCreationInformation wci = new WebCreationInf...

this.ClientContext.Web.Webs.Add(wci);
this.ClientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
```

Could anyone explain why am I getting the Security exception? Thanks.

I've asked the same question [here at SharePoint overflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25964/cannot-create-site-in-different-site-collection-silverlight-client-object-mode).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is the security restriction applied by Silverlight's Client Object Model. It can, however, be overcome by adding client access policy file to the root folder of the SharePoint’s web application as described [here](http://snahta.blogspot.com/2010/05/silverlight-security-error-connecting.html). More details can be found in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx).